# Sub-Categories in a Community Site

Tags: community, categories

Can you create Sub-Categories in a community site?

I have a customer who likes the categories but wants to break it down even further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say add a Managed Metadata column. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Managed-Metadata-column-8fad9e35-a618-4400-b3c7-46f02785d27f#__toc355082380

Sorry... This link works.

Comment: the link is busted

Comment: That worked.. Its not as intuitive as I would have liked but the customer was happy and at least you can put it into the left navigation so its pretty easy for the user to navigate.

Comment: Very happy that solution worked for you. Remember you can also search by the managed metadata terms and it will also add refiners for you based on the terms or term sets specified. Very handy when trying to search for categorized content. Thanks for letting me know it worked.